# Docker takes a long time to start mysql

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the follow docker compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db-production:
    container_name: mysql-production
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dota2learning-db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db-production:/home/db-production
  db-testing:
    container_name: mysql-testing
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db-testing:/home/db-testing
volumes:
  data:
```

I also have a sql script to dump my database. The problem that's docker take a long time to start mysql and the script don't work.

I tried add the follow command on docker compose file:

```
command: mysql --user=root --password=toor dota2learning-db < /home/db-production/dumb-db-production.sql
```

This command does not work because it tries to run before the mysql server is working.

I know because as soon as I created the container I got into it and tried to log into mysql and it wasn't available yet:

```
sudo docker exec -it mysql-production bash
```

on container:

```
mysql --user=root --password=toor

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I also tried to start MySQL manually:

```
root@4c91b5407561:/# mysqld start
2022-06-20T14:56:18.448123Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 97
2022-06-20T14:56:18.451281Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2022-06-20T14:56:18.451346Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-06-20T14:56:18.451514Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

That's add the follow command on docker compose don't work:

```
command: mysqld start
```

**NOTE:**
But I know that if I wait 1 or 2 minutes mysql will be available to run the script though, I want to run this script automatically and not manually.

When I add the **commands** on docker compose the docker container keeps restarting forever, because it keeps trying to execute the commands and mysql is not available yet.

Comment: There's some discussion of this in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).  It's normal for a database container to take 30-60 seconds to start up.  Depending on your host OS, it may be faster to use a named volume than a bind mount (you won't be able to directly edit the database files either way).

Comment: Thanks for help Davida... Can I close here?